# Is it possible to have an Image dropdown in React-native?

Tags: image, react-native, dropdown

I have that dropdown made with react-native-material-dropdown-v2
with this list when I click :

[image]

[image]

I would like to transform this line on an icon (image) that shows the dropdown when I click on it, is it possible ?
Thanks a lot !

The code I use for now :

```
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
              <MaterialDropdown
                label={i18n.t("mytrips.date.date")}
                data={data_dropdown}
                baseColor="#212121"
                labelFontSize={17}
                textColor="#212121"
                itemColor="#212121"
                selectedItemColor="#000"
                backgroundColor="transparent"
                pickerStyle={styles.dropdownPickerStyle}
                affixTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                itemTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                labelTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                containerStyle={styles.dropdownContainerStyle}
                itemCount={10}
                dropdownPosition={-4.5}
                labelExtractor={({ label }) => label}
                valueExtractor={({ value }) => value}
                propsExtractor={({ props }, index) => props}
                onChangeText={(value) => this.choiceAction(value)}
                useNativeDriver={true}            
              />
 </View>
```

I've seen that I can maybe use :

```
renderAccessory={()=>
              <View style={{width:50, borderWidth:1}}>
                <Image source={require("../../assets/images/icon_rotation.png")} 
                style={{ width: 30, height: 30, resizeMode: 'contain'}} />
              </View>}
```

But nothing changes when I add this...

Comment: Can u show your code ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, I edited my post with the code.